# Why Router works after manual rebooting?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have TP-Link Wireless  Router (Model TL-WR720N ), it stops works often, but if I manually turn off the electricity, and switch on, it starts to work again.
I can't reboot the router using firmware from my computer as I can not connect the address `http://192.168.0.1/` (default IP address). I have seen this in other routers too, some of them do not need to be rebooted manually as those router were being connected through the firmware with their default IP address.

What is the exact reason of this kind of malfunction that starts working fine once it is rebooted?

Comment: Do a hard reset of the TP Link back to factory specifications. Then you should be able to access the Router by its default address and then upgrade the firmware.  That normally works in a situation like this.

Comment: @John I want to learn the reason.

Comment: On any recent router I have used, it is always possible to get to the default address. I / we cannot tell you what happened inside the router not to permit this. I assume your computer is working properly. So then at this point, router reset is the reasonable course of action at this point.

Comment: Are you torrenting/p2p-ing when it happens? Does it do it over a set amount of time?